# будет какая-то проблема з установкой windows?

Tags: windows, usb, ноутбук

На ноутбуке не работает usb 2.0 но есть 3.0, при установке windows 10 с флешки 2.0, будет какая-то проблема з установкой windows?

Comment: Нет, USB 2.0 совместима с USB 3.0. Просто если подключить устройство USB 2.0 в разъём 3.0, то работать оно будет на уровне 2.0. Если подключить устройство USB 3.0 к разъёму 2.0, то работать оно тоже будет на уровне 2.0.

Comment: Не будет, разве что скорость работы может быть пониже, так как USB 2.0 медленнее

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев установка windows с флэшки 2.0 через интерфейс 3.0 пройдет успешно (единственное что будет падение скорости так как скорость работы флэшки не позволяет полностью "раскрыть" интерфейс 3.0) при этом иногда могут возникнуть трудности если на материнской плате используется "хитрый" контроллер который "не понимает" BOIS - но это редкость